# Retrieve a complex object from ActionParameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter

I am working on an MVC project where controller actions deal with Assets. Different controllers take in the assetId parameter in different way: Some controllers simply get `int assetId`, other `int id`, and other using a complex object `AssetDTO dto` (which contains a property that holds the assetId)

I am writing an ActionFilter that is added to the action method and is provided with the actionParameter name where I can get the asset value.

Action Method:

```
    [AssetIdFilter("assetId")]
    public ActionResult Index(int assetId)
    {
            ...
    }
```

The attribute is defined as:

```
public class AssetIdFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string _assetIdParameterKey { get; set; }

    public AssetIdFilterAttribute (string assetIdParameterKey)
    {
        _assetIdParameterKey = assetIdParameterKey;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        int assetId;
        if (Int32.TryParse(filterContext.ActionParameters[_assetIdParameterKey].ToString(), out assetId))
        {
                    ......
        }
    }
```

This works as expected, but will only work when the assetId is provided as a primitive. I am not sure what to do when the assetId is provided within a complex object into the action method.

Will I need to parse each object differently depending on the type? I am hoping I can specify some kind of dot-notation in the AssetIdFilter to tell it where the assetId is located: dto.assetId

Any way I can use dynamics? or reflection?? ect.???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

and here **dynamic** comes to the rescue.you can change the actionFilterAttribute to be :

```
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            dynamic assetIdHolder = filterContext.ActionParameters[_assetIdParameterKey];
            if (assetIdHolder.GetType().IsPrimitive)
            {
                //do whatever with assetIdHolder              
            }
            else
            {
                //do whatever with assetIdHolder.assetId
            }
        }
```

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, you answered your question. One way would be to use dot notation:

```
//simple case:
[AssetId("id")]
public ActionResult Index(string id) {
    //code here
}

//complex case:
[AssetId("idObj", AssetIdProperty = "SubObj.id")]
public ActionResult index(IdObject idObj) {
    //code here
}
```

And `AssetIdAttribute` is as follows:

```
public class AssetIdAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string _assetIdParameterKey { get; set; }

    public string AssetIdProperty { get; set; }

    public AssetIdFilterAttribute(string assetIdParameterKey)
    {
        _assetIdParameterKey = assetIdParameterKey;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        int assetId;
        var param = filterContext.ActionParameters[_assetIdParameterKey];
        int.TryParse(GetPropertyValue(param, this.AssetIdProperty).ToString(), out assetId);
        //you code continues here.
    }

    private static string GetPropertyValue(object souce, string property)
    {
        var propNames = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(property) || !property.Contains('.') ? new string[] { } : property.Split('.');
        var result = souce;
        foreach (var prop in propNames)
        {
            result = result.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(result);
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

The code does not have null checks when calling `ToString` and when calling `GetProperty` though. Also, it does not check the success of `TryParse`. Please apply these corrections when used.

Maybe this code could be written using `dynamic`, but at the end `dynamic` usage is compiled into object using reflection (something like what I have done here), thus no big difference to me.

Also, maybe it would be more clear to have a parameter like "idObj.SubObj.id", but that again depends on the preference, and the code will become *a little bit* more complex.